# Get values from 2 columns of each row, Round them and finally sort them

Tags: php, sql, sorting, rounding

Just want to quickly say that i am not a "php/sql programmer" , i understand the basics but not the more advanced stuff witch is giving me a hard time sometimes (like now) Sorry for my bad english by the way, im from sweden :)

Okey , i am about to create a Dreamcast database online where everyone can find specific information about games such as how many VMU blocks a specific game requires to save or simply to sort out the games that supports the VGA adapter and so on. (site can be found on dreamcastdb.com , please beware its only a couple of days old so its still far from finished,every dreamcast game out there , released and unreleased will be on this site before i die, thats a promise)

I have a "games" table whith one row for each game , as for now i only have 3 games in the database. in the rows i have 2 columns thats of interest for this question, nrvotes and sumvotes , each time a visitor votes on a game the nrvotes will be +1 and the sumvotes increases with the score he/she voted (1-10).

I want on my index.php (first page) to show the 3 games with the highest score wich means i have to selet all games in my games db , and "round" the value i get from sumvotes/nrvotes then finally sort them , finally i want to show the top 3.

As for now my code looks like this but it isnt working at all.

```
query = select from * games order by (round ($sumvotes/$nrvotes,2) DESC LIMIT 3;";
```

I didnt understand how to post proper php code here , i was prompted with an error message but ill think you got my point , this code isnt doing what i want.

Okey thats what it looks like for the moment, im aware that if this would work it will only show the cover of the games and in the right order (highest score on top), as for now ill only show the covers finally ill add the titles and the score of cource.

I would really appreciate some help by the more experienced php/sql programmers.

Thanks in advance , Florian from Sweden , a dreamcast fanboy :)

Comment: To clarify my problem a bit more:
The database will contain over 400 Dreamcast games when 
all is complete, each row in this database is one game. 
In each row there is 2 columns that interesting in this 
question, NRVOTES and SUMVOTES , each time a visitor 
votes NRVOTES will increase with one and SUMVOTES will 
increase with 1-10 depending on what the visitor voted.
The php code i want to use is going to get the value 
SUMVOTES divided to NRVOTES (SUMVOTES/NRVOTES) and then 
only show the 3 higest ratings by 2 decimal.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to work with an array.
Make a while loop, and than check if the votes are higher than the 3 in the database.
If so, put it in the array by overwriting it.

Something like that?

Good luck with that! :)

Answer (score 0):

Dividing integer by integer gives you integer as result. If you convert one of the votes count to decimal, it should be good

```
SELECT * FROM games order by round(decimal(10,2),sumvotes/numvotes) desc
```